# How to create sliding effect in carousel using Bootstrap5?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

I want to **implement a carousel** and for that I referred to the [documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/components/carousel/#with-controls) for it in **Bootstrap v5.1**. Though the code is showing the carousel and is working but the slides are **changing statically** and I want to add the **sliding effect in the carousel** while moving the slides with arrows. Please refer some resources to learn that. Or in case something is wrong with my code then here it is:

```html
  <!-- CSS bootstrap -->
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-F3w7mX95PdgyTmZZMECAngseQB83DfGTowi0iMjiWaeVhAn4FJkqJByhZMI3AhiU" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <!-- JS bootstrap -->
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-/bQdsTh/da6pkI1MST/rWKFNjaCP5gBSY4sEBT38Q/9RBh9AH40zEOg7Hlq2THRZ" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <!-- CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">
</head>
<body>
  <section id="testimonials">
    <div id="testimonial-carousel" class="carousel slide" data-bs-ride="false">
      <div class="carousel-inner">
        <div class="carousel-item active">
          <h2>…..</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item">
          <h2 >…</h2>
        </div>
      </div>
      <button class="carousel-control-prev" type="button" data-bs-target="#testimonial-carousel" data-bs-slide="prev">
        <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon"></span>
      </button>
      <button class="carousel-control-next" type="button" data-bs-target="#testimonial-carousel" data-bs-slide="next">
        <span class="carousel-control-next-icon"></span>
      </button>
    </div>
  </section>
```

Comment: What happens if you change `data-bs-ride` to `carousel` (from `false`)? You're loading the JS but haven't initialised it (in the code you shared) so the animation code may not be running. The animation should be applied because you've included the `slide` class.

Comment: What do you mean by sliding effect. It is already sliding smoothly from left to right

Comment: @JohnP it is still not showing the animation after changing data-bs-ride to carousel. Also, how can I initialize JS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by adding the custom transition in CSS.

```
.carousel-item {
   transition: transform .6s ease-in-out;
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Here:

demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/demo-slides-utnot?file=/index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
    <link
      href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
      rel="stylesheet"
      integrity="sha384-F3w7mX95PdgyTmZZMECAngseQB83DfGTowi0iMjiWaeVhAn4FJkqJByhZMI3AhiU"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    />
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>
      <div
        id="carouselExampleControls"
        class="carousel slide"
        data-bs-ride="carousel"
      >
        <div class="carousel-inner">
          <div class="carousel-item active">
            <img
              src="https://i.ibb.co/cvpntL1/hats.png"
              class="d-block w-100"
              alt="..."
            />
          </div>
          <div class="carousel-item">
            <img
              src="https://i.ibb.co/px2tCc3/jackets.png"
              class="d-block w-100"
              alt="..."
            />
          </div>
          <div class="carousel-item">
            <img
              src="https://i.ibb.co/0jqHpnp/sneakers.png"
              class="d-block w-100"
              alt="..."
            />
          </div>
        </div>
        <button
          class="carousel-control-prev"
          type="button"
          data-bs-target="#carouselExampleControls"
          data-bs-slide="prev"
        >
          <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
          <span class="visually-hidden">Previous</span>
        </button>
        <button
          class="carousel-control-next"
          type="button"
          data-bs-target="#carouselExampleControls"
          data-bs-slide="next"
        >
          <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
          <span class="visually-hidden">Next</span>
        </button>
      </div>
    </h1>

    <script
      src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
      integrity="sha384-/bQdsTh/da6pkI1MST/rWKFNjaCP5gBSY4sEBT38Q/9RBh9AH40zEOg7Hlq2THRZ"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    ></script>
  </body>
</html>
```